# Scanning line of input with char and num

Tags: c, pointers

So I'm doing this problem where I need to calculate the average using pointers and without using strings. The user will input a letter and then a space followed by a number(an integer), the letter indicating if the number is positive(p) or negative(n) or if the user is done input-ing numbers(e).

I know I need a loop to continually read in number and add or subtract them from the sum until the letter "e" is input.

```
 program should have and use the following function
//    Precondition: value will be a pointer to where the input value is to     be stored. 
//    Postcondition: returns true if a number was read, or false if 
//    it was the end of the list. The int pointed to by value will be
//    set to the number input by this function, made negative or
//    positive depending on the character before it. int read_number(int*     value);
```

A sample input being p 20 p 20 p 10 p 10 e

output: 15

My problem as of now is my loop is only reading for two cycles of input, and even then it isn't printing the average. Also I'm supposed to use a pointer but given the directions i'm still not sure what the context is, I'm not seeing where a pointer is useful.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//precondition: value will be a pointer to where the input value is to be stored.
int main(){

    int sum;
    int num;
    int counter;
    float avg;
    char let;
 scanf("%c %d", &let, &num);
    for (counter=0;let == 'n' || let == 'p'; counter++){
        scanf("%c %d", &let, &num);
                if ( let == 'n'){
                sum-=num;
                }
                if (let == 'p'){
                sum+=num;
                }
        if ( let == 'e'){
             avg=sum/counter;
            printf("%f", &avg);
        }

            }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: My loop is only reading for two cycles of input, and even then it isn't printing the average. Also I'm supposed to use a pointer but given the directions i'm still not sure what the context is, I'm not seeing where a pointer is useful, then again i'm new to C.

Comment: You should add that to the question.

Comment: You don't have to say you are using C if the `c` tag has been added.

Comment: right, just wanted to make sure anyone viewing knew.

Answer (score 1):

Your input is:`p 20 p 20 p 10 p
10 e`.
The `scanf` before the loop scans `'p'` and then skips the space and then scans `20`. The next `scanf` in the loop reads the space as it is also a character and the `%d` fails to scan an `int` and the stops scanning. See the problem?

To fix it, change

```
scanf("%c %d", &let, &num);
```

To

```
scanf(" %c %d", &let, &num);//Note the space before %c
```

The space before `%c` gobbles up whitespace characters(if any) like newlines, spaces etc until the first non whitespace character.

Other problems include not initializing `sum` to 0 and using `&avg` instead of `avg` in the `printf` below

```
printf("%f", &avg);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I added the space, and confirmed the numbers are being read in and addressed to the variables but my average is still not printing, I have also initialized sum to be equal to zero.

Comment: Ah. Your loop will execute only when `let` is `'p'` or `'n'`. When you type `'e'`, `let == 'n' || let == 'p'` becomes false, the loop breaks and the program ends. Fix it by removing `if ( let == 'e'){...}` and move `avg=sum/counter; printf("%f", avg);` after the loop, outside the loop before `return 0;`.

Comment: I've changed these  but it still doesn't end when I input e, it ends after 2 inputs no matter what they are, and it still prints the average as 0

Comment: @Phlash6 ,Hmm. Edit your question to include the code that you have. Do not remove the current code present in the question. That would make my answer meaningless.